# Regex pattern match with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following data in a file, which is repeated multiple times:

> Date:21
>   Month:03
>   Year:2017
>   Amount:50
>   Category:Grocery
>   Account:bank
>   Note:expensive

Now, I want to extract the value after "Amount:", i.e. "50".

I'm using the following code in PHP:

```
$result = preg_split("/Amount/", $contents);
$truncated = substr($printresult, 1, 2);
print_r($truncated);
```

The result I'm getting is this:

```
    Da50
```

Could you please help me figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong in this code?

Thank you.

[Edit: $contents contains all the string data]

This is the entire code: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/hwj7IiPUcd
Content of data.txt is this: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/5TxWH8MUX

Comment: @chris85 added a link to the code. Please take a look.

Comment: The content of data.txt is here: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/5TxWH8MUX

Comment: @chris85 I'm horribly sorry. Too much editing before posting here: anyway here it is: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/hwj7IiPUcd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following *regex* pattern ...

```
(?<=Amount:)\d+
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FCGSq3/1)**

**PHP** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/Xlc2Ta) )

```
$regex = '/(?<=Amount:)\d+/';
$arraynext = file_get_contents('data.txt');
preg_match_all($regex, $arraynext, $result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I'll recheck the code, I get "DaCa" as a result in my code for some reason.

Comment: @n00b12345 whats the contents of `data.txt` ?

Comment: @n00b12345 replace all the lines after `// Retrieve data from file and process` with the above code

Comment: @n00b12345 `Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.` The response time of an answer has (should have) no baring on what you should accept. Whatever resolved your question should be what you pick.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
    $subject = "Date:21 Month:03 Year:2017 Amount:50 Category:Grocery Account:bank Note:expensive";

$pattern = "/Account/";

    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I get "mo" as result.

Comment: I am getting Account.

Comment: I just added a link to the entire code, if possible please take a look.

Comment: This answer is 100% wrong!  How did it earn +3 votes?  SO is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The `da` comes from the `Date` at the start of your string. You need to use `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` to extract exact matches. `preg_split` splits on the found term, index 0 you don't care about. Try:

```
$arraynext = 'Date:21
Month:03
Year:2017
Amount:50
Category:Wow
Account:The
Note:This';
$endresult = preg_match("/\s*Amount:\s*(\d+)/", $arraynext, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/SA48sm/1/

PHP Demo: https://3v4l.org/6jaCV

Answer (score 1):

If you say that you have many coincidences, then you need to select all

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=Amount:)[\d]{0,}/', $contents, $result);
foreach($result as $res) {
    print_r($res);
}
```

Comment: This answer does not use regex best practice!  The use of a character class and the greedy quantifier expression are not thoughtful.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this pattern: `/Amount:\K\d+/`
> It will accurately extract the full desired numeric value that follows each `Amount:` without using the much less efficient "lookarounds".

My web filter software does not let me visit your pastelabs links, so I cannot see your actual input.  (This is one of many reasons why you should post your input samples directly into your question.)  You state that you have several lines which you must extract from, so this is the sample input that I have tested with:

```
Date:21 Month:03 Year:2017 Amount:50 Category:Grocery Account:bank Note:expensive
Date:1 Month:04 Year:2017 Amount:150 Category:Grocery Account:bank Note:expensive
Date:14 Month:04 Year:2017 Amount:5 Category:Grocery Account:bank Note:expensive
Date:28 Month:04 Year:2017 Amount:5935 Category:Grocery Account:bank Note:expensive
```

My pattern captures the desired results in just **48 steps**.  ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FCGSq3/2))
The pattern uses `\K` which means "KEEP the character starting from this point", so there is no need for a capture group, nor a "lookbehind".
If your actual input data has optional spaces between `Amount:` and the number value, then just add `?` (space then question mark) to the pattern after the `:`.

When used with `preg_match_all()`, the output array is as small as `preg_match_all()` can make: an array containing 1 subarray with 4 elements.  I cut directly to the subarray in my code to follow:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33ee3529458982ff27da371a6075753494c658eb))

```
$in='Date:21 Month:03 Year:2017 Amount:50 Category:Grocery Account:bank Note:expensive
Date:1 Month:04 Year:2017 Amount:150 Category:Grocery Account:bank Note:expensive
Date:14 Month:04 Year:2017 Amount:5 Category:Grocery Account:bank Note:expensive
Date:28 Month:04 Year:2017 Amount:5935 Category:Grocery Account:bank Note:expensive';

var_export(preg_match_all('/Amount:\K\d+/',$in,$out)?$out[0]:[]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '50',
  1 => '150',
  2 => '5',
  3 => '5935',
)
```

---

As far as the other answers on this page, they all process my test data in over **600** steps (more than 12x slower / less efficient than my pattern).  At the time of this post, one of them is completely wrong, and some use sloppy regex syntax and shouldn't be learned from.